# Error in forecast and accuracy function in R

Tags: r, time-series, data-science, predict

I want to train an arima model and want some forecast.

So I am doing this:

```
arima<-function(train, val, column)
{
model = auto.arima(train[[column]], trace=TRUE, stepwise=FALSE, approximation = FALSE)
acc=accuracy(model)
pred=forecast(model, length(val[[column]]))
acc=accuracy(pred, val[[column]])
return(acc)
}
```

Then I am getting this error:

> Error in accuracy.default(pred, val[[column]]):
> First argument should be a forecast object or a time series.

According to me pred should be a forecast object.

pred right now :

```
$pred
Time Series:
Start=220
End=220
Frequency=1
[1] 2.72
$se
Time Series:
Start=220
End=220
Frequency=1
[1] 0.13
```

Please give me some advice I am stuck here...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing to `accuracy(forecast(pred))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pred` object suggests you've loaded a package that is over-writing the `forecast()` function. My guess is you have loaded `greybox` or `smooth` after you have loaded `forecast`.